# I have setup munin how do I set up alerts for specific parameters

Tags: linux, monitoring, munin

I have setup alerts in munin.conf

```
contacts user1 user2 user3 user4
contact.user1.command mail -s "Munin notification" mailid1@mydomain.in
contact.user2.command mail -s "Munin notification" mailid2@mydomain.in
contact.user3.command mail -s "Munin notification" mailid3@mydomain.in
contact.user4.command mail -s "Munin notification" mailid4@mydomain.in
contact.user1.always_send critical
contact.user2.always_send warning critical
contact.user3.always_send warning critical
contact.user4.always_send critical
```

But this is likely to send me notifications when any of the parameters  hit the warning or critical threshold. Is there a way to set alerts for only a specific set of parameters, In my case I would like to set it up only for : cpu utilization, memory utilization, load average, and disk utilization

Unfortunately the Munin documentation is silent on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can suppress notifications for specific plug-ins using the [plugin level directive](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/munin.conf#Pluginleveldirectives) `contacts`. From the documentation:

> contacts: Enables (by naming contacts) or disables ("no") warnings through external system

They have an example, in the [sample `munin.conf`](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/munin.conf#Samplemunin.conf):

```
  df.contacts no     # Don't warn (...) if the 'df' plugin exceed warning values.
```

Comment: This leads me to ask another question How do I get the plugin names? Do they default to the file names?

Comment: I don't have a munin installation available to check, but look at the information on the package for your linux distribution and you may find it there. For instance, the [list of files from the Debian package](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/all/munin-plugins-core/filelist) may help you.

Comment: To get final plugin names to match against, it's useful to look at the names of the RRD files in `/var/lib/munin` on the master, which are in turn generated from what's in the output of `munin-run pluginname config` on the nodes