# Configuring Munin alerts on a per-command basis

Tags: munin

I help administer a number of servers which use Munin for monitoring, and currently have all alert emails going to a specific monitoring email list.

However, I would like *some* (but not all) alerts to also go to a second monitoring list; specifically I'd like the free space alerts to go to all users of these servers.

From the question "[How do I set up alerts for specific parameters](https://serverfault.com/questions/532319/i-have-setup-munin-how-do-i-set-up-alerts-for-specific-parameters)" I know how to disable alerts for all contacts, but I'm not finding anything about only enabling specific alerts for specific contacts.

My `local.conf` is currently something like this:

```
contact.admins.command mail -s "[munin] ${var:host}: ${var:graph_title} status ${var:worst}" admins-list@example.com
contact.admins.always_send warning critical
contact.admins.text (admin-oriented alert email text redacted for clarity)

contact.users.command mail -s "Storage on ${var:host} is currently ${var:worst}" users-list@example.com
contact.users.text (user-oriented alert email text redacted for clarity)

[group;servername]
    address servername.example.com
    df.warning 0:90
    df.critical 0:95
    contacts admins
```

and what I'd like is for the `df` warnings (and *only* the `df` warnings) to also go to `users`.

From the [munin documentation](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/munin.conf) it seems that I can somehow configure the contacts on a per-plugin basis, but there are no examples given, and ideally I'd like to only have this on some, rather than all, hosts (although it's not a big deal if it can't be limited on a per-host basis).

Comment: I'd use a wrapper script for `contact.admin.command` that checks the message and if it concerns `df` then also notify the users.

Comment: @wurtel That seems like it would be difficult to do well, especially when I want entirely different messages for both. I'll consider that as a possible approach though.